# Python struct unpack binary com data

Tags: python, struct, unpack

I'm unpacking some byte data I received. I have following the structure record(attached). Unfortunately, my data is encased in C style struct(s) within other structs so it makes unpacking difficult for me.
Please see attached screenshot. I'm attempting to unpack p_group but noticed their this a p1224[4] and I'm unsure how to unpack this: (I know struct group_hdr is LH, and I've ignored struct ecg_group for simplicity). It's been tough to find literature on this online. Thanks your help!

```
hdr_data = struct.unpack_from('<LHhhhh', b,offset=0)
#or
hdr_data = struct.unpack_from('<LHhhhh'*4, b,offset=0)
```

[image: data structure]

Answer (score 0):

It's the latter.

The `[4]` indicates that both the `group_hdr` and the individual `short`s are multiplied by 4.